# How can we debug an SSL error more precisely?

Tags: java, ssl

I have a problem with using ssl in WLP at a customers project. And we try to find the problem.

The story so far:

I am using HTTPClient 5.1, jsse-1.2 is in classhpath, transportSecurity-1.0 is active in the wlp feature manager, the truststore and keystore options are both set in the server.xml.

The CloseableHttpClient is currently built like:

```java
private void buildClient() throws MalformedURLException {

  try {
      URL aURL = new URL(BASE_URL);
    String host = aURL.getAuthority();

    SSLContext ctx = SSLContexts.createDefault();

        final SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = SSLConnectionSocketFactoryBuilder.create()
                .setSslContext(ctx)
                .setTlsVersions(TLS.V_1_2)
                .build();

        final BasicCredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
        credsProvider.setCredentials(
                new AuthScope(host, 443),
                new UsernamePasswordCredentials(USER, PASSWORD.toCharArray()));
        
  
        final HttpClientConnectionManager cm = PoolingHttpClientConnectionManagerBuilder.create()
            .setSSLSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory)
                .build();           

        
    httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
                .setConnectionManager(cm)
                .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider)
                .build();
  } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    throw new MalformedURLException(BASE_URL);
  }
}
```

And the logging looks like this:

```
[2022-02-15T16:21:39] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-7] client5.http.impl.classic.InternalHttpClient:164 - ex-0000000001 preparing request execution
[2022-02-15T16:21:39] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-7] hc.client5.http.protocol.RequestAddCookies:122 - ex-0000000001 Cookie spec selected: strict
[2022-02-15T16:21:39] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-7] hc.client5.http.protocol.RequestAuthCache:78 - ex-0000000001 Auth cache not set in the context
[2022-02-15T16:21:39] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-7] client5.http.impl.classic.ProtocolExec:164 - ex-0000000001 target auth state: UNCHALLENGED
[2022-02-15T16:21:39] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-7] client5.http.impl.classic.ProtocolExec:170 - ex-0000000001 proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
[2022-02-15T16:21:39] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-7] client5.http.impl.classic.ConnectExec:117 - ex-0000000001 acquiring connection with route {s}->https://test.doesnt.matter:443
[2022-02-15T16:21:39] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-7] client5.http.impl.classic.InternalHttpClient:101 - ex-0000000001 acquiring endpoint (3 MINUTES)
[2022-02-15T16:21:39] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-7] client5.http.impl.io.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager:255 - ex-0000000001 endpoint lease request (3 MINUTES) [route: {s}->https://test.doesnt.matter:443][total available: 0; route allocated: 0 of 5; total allocated: 0 of 25]
[2022-02-15T16:21:39] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-7] client5.http.impl.io.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager:277 - ex-0000000001 endpoint leased [route: {s}->https://test.doesnt.matter:443][total available: 0; route allocated: 1 of 5; total allocated: 1 of 25]
[2022-02-15T16:21:39] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-7] client5.http.impl.io.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager:307 - ex-0000000001 acquired ep-0000000000
[2022-02-15T16:21:39] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-7] client5.http.impl.classic.InternalHttpClient:116 - ex-0000000001 acquired endpoint ep-0000000000
[2022-02-15T16:21:39] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-7] client5.http.impl.classic.ConnectExec:124 - ex-0000000001 opening connection {s}->https://test.doesnt.matter:443
[2022-02-15T16:21:39] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-7] client5.http.impl.classic.InternalHttpClient:156 - ep-0000000000 connecting endpoint (3 MINUTES)
[2022-02-15T16:21:39] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-7] client5.http.impl.io.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager:392 - ep-0000000000 connecting endpoint to https://test.doesnt.matter:443 (3 MINUTES)
[2022-02-15T16:21:39] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-7] client5.http.impl.io.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator:145 - http-outgoing-0 connecting to test.doesnt.matter/4.XXX.XXX.16:443
[2022-02-15T16:21:39] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-7] hc.client5.http.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory:211 - Connecting socket to test.doesnt.matter/4.XXX.XXX.16:443 with timeout 3 MINUTES
[2022-02-15T16:21:39] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-7] hc.client5.http.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory:267 - Enabled protocols: [TLSv1.2]
[2022-02-15T16:21:39] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-7] hc.client5.http.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory:268 - Enabled cipher suites: [SSL_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, SSL_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, SSL_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, SSL_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, SSL_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, SSL_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, SSL_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, SSL_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, SSL_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, SSL_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, SSL_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, SSL_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, SSL_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, SSL_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, SSL_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, SSL_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, SSL_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, SSL_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, SSL_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, SSL_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, SSL_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SSL_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SSL_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SSL_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
[2022-02-15T16:21:39] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-7] hc.client5.http.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory:272 - Starting handshake
[2022-02-15T16:21:39] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-7] client5.http.impl.io.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection:174 - http-outgoing-0 close connection IMMEDIATE
[2022-02-15T16:21:39] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-7] client5.http.impl.classic.InternalHttpClient:236 - ep-0000000000 endpoint closed
[2022-02-15T16:21:39] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-7] client5.http.impl.classic.InternalHttpClient:240 - ep-0000000000 discarding endpoint
[2022-02-15T16:21:39] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-7] client5.http.impl.io.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager:336 - ep-0000000000 releasing endpoint
[2022-02-15T16:21:39] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-7] client5.http.impl.io.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager:359 - ep-0000000000 connection is not kept alive
[2022-02-15T16:21:39] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-7] client5.http.impl.io.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager:368 - ep-0000000000 connection released [route: {s}->https://test.doesnt.matter:443][total available: 0; route allocated: 0 of 5; total allocated: 0 of 25]
```

Then we get the sslException:

```
[2022-02-15T16:21:39] [ERROR] [Default Executor-thread-7] main.java.refSystems.fiservice.FiServiceClient:202 - SSL-Fehler: PKIX path building failed: com.ibm.security.cert.IBMCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: com.ibm.security.cert.IBMCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at com.ibm.jsse2.g.a(g.java:58) ~[?:8.0 build_20201204--193]
    at com.ibm.jsse2.ba.a(ba.java:38) ~[?:8.0 build_20201204--193]
    at com.ibm.jsse2.ba.a(ba.java:101) ~[?:8.0 build_20201204--193]
    at com.ibm.jsse2.ba.a(ba.java:62) ~[?:8.0 build_20201204--193]
    at com.ibm.jsse2.y$c.a(y$c.java:166) ~[?:8.0 build_20201204--193]
    at com.ibm.jsse2.A$c.consume(A$c.java:2) ~[?:8.0 build_20201204--193]
    at com.ibm.jsse2.p.consume(p.java:43) ~[?:8.0 build_20201204--193]
    at com.ibm.jsse2.Z.a(Z.java:73) ~[?:8.0 build_20201204--193]
    at com.ibm.jsse2.Z.a(Z.java:245) ~[?:8.0 build_20201204--193]
    at com.ibm.jsse2.ba.a(ba.java:116) ~[?:8.0 build_20201204--193]
    at com.ibm.jsse2.aZ.a(aZ.java:36) ~[?:8.0 build_20201204--193]
    at com.ibm.jsse2.bi.b(bi.java:219) ~[?:8.0 build_20201204--193]
    at com.ibm.jsse2.bi.f(bi.java:317) ~[?:8.0 build_20201204--193]
    at com.ibm.jsse2.bi.a(bi.java:218) ~[?:8.0 build_20201204--193]
    at com.ibm.jsse2.bi.startHandshake(bi.java:212) ~[?:8.0 build_20201204--193]
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:273) ~[httpclient5-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:241) ~[httpclient5-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.io.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:148) ~[httpclient5-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.io.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:396) ~[httpclient5-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.InternalExecRuntime.connectEndpoint(InternalExecRuntime.java:158) ~[httpclient5-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.InternalExecRuntime.connectEndpoint(InternalExecRuntime.java:168) ~[httpclient5-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ConnectExec.execute(ConnectExec.java:136) ~[httpclient5-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51) ~[httpclient5-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement$1.proceed(ExecChainElement.java:57) ~[httpclient5-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:175) ~[httpclient5-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51) ~[httpclient5-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement$1.proceed(ExecChainElement.java:57) ~[httpclient5-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.HttpRequestRetryExec.execute(HttpRequestRetryExec.java:96) ~[httpclient5-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51) ~[httpclient5-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement$1.proceed(ExecChainElement.java:57) ~[httpclient5-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ContentCompressionExec.execute(ContentCompressionExec.java:133) ~[httpclient5-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51) ~[httpclient5-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement$1.proceed(ExecChainElement.java:57) ~[httpclient5-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:115) ~[httpclient5-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51) ~[httpclient5-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:170) ~[httpclient5-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:75) ~[httpclient5-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:89) ~[httpclient5-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
    at main.java.refSystems.fiservice.FiServiceClient.sendRequest(FiServiceClient.java:187) [classes/:?]
    at main.java.refSystems.fiservice.FiServiceClient.isAvailable(FiServiceClient.java:146) [classes/:?]
    at main.java.refSystems.fiservice.FiServiceFunctions.isAvailable(FiServiceFunctions.java:99) [classes/:?]
    at main.java.atc.definitions.ReferenceSystem.isAvailable(ReferenceSystem.java:78) [classes/:?]
    at main.java.timer.AvailableInterface.isAvailable(AvailableInterface.java:66) [classes/:?]
    at main.java.timer.AvailableInterface.checkAllSystems(AvailableInterface.java:39) [classes/:?]
    at main.java.handler.StatusHandler.refreshParameter(StatusHandler.java:32) [classes/:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90) ~[?:1.8.0]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55) ~[?:1.8.0]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508) ~[?:1.8.0]
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:245) [com.ibm.ws.org.apache.jasper.el.3.0_3.0.47.jar:?]
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:267) [com.ibm.ws.org.apache.jasper.el.3.0_3.0.47.jar:?]
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.ContextAwareTagMethodExpression.invoke(ContextAwareTagMethodExpression.java:96) [com.ibm.ws.org.apache.myfaces.2.3_1.0.47.jar:2.3.6]
    at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:83) [com.ibm.websphere.javaee.jsf.2.3_1.0.47.jar:?]
    at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:58) [com.ibm.websphere.javaee.jsf.2.3_1.0.47.jar:?]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:429) [com.ibm.websphere.javaee.jsf.2.3_1.0.47.jar:?]
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:103) [com.ibm.websphere.javaee.jsf.2.3_1.0.47.jar:?]
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot._broadcastAll(UIViewRoot.java:1255) [com.ibm.websphere.javaee.jsf.2.3_1.0.47.jar:?]
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:420) [com.ibm.websphere.javaee.jsf.2.3_1.0.47.jar:?]
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot._process(UIViewRoot.java:1741) [com.ibm.websphere.javaee.jsf.2.3_1.0.47.jar:?]
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:935) [com.ibm.websphere.javaee.jsf.2.3_1.0.47.jar:?]
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationExecutor.execute(InvokeApplicationExecutor.java:42) [com.ibm.ws.org.apache.myfaces.2.3_1.0.47.jar:2.3.6]
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:195) [com.ibm.ws.org.apache.myfaces.2.3_1.0.47.jar:2.3.6]
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:142) [com.ibm.ws.org.apache.myfaces.2.3_1.0.47.jar:2.3.6]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:204) [com.ibm.websphere.javaee.jsf.2.3_1.0.47.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1230) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.47.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:729) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.47.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:426) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.47.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1226) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.47.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1010) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.47.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:75) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.47.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer40.servlet.CacheServletWrapper40.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper40.java:83) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.4.0_1.0.47.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:936) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.47.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.run(DynamicVirtualHost.java:279) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.47.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink$TaskWrapper.run(HttpDispatcherLink.java:1141) [com.ibm.ws.transport.http_1.0.47.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink.wrapHandlerAndExecute(HttpDispatcherLink.java:422) [com.ibm.ws.transport.http_1.0.47.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink.ready(HttpDispatcherLink.java:381) [com.ibm.ws.transport.http_1.0.47.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:565) [com.ibm.ws.transport.http_1.0.47.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:499) [com.ibm.ws.transport.http_1.0.47.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:359) [com.ibm.ws.transport.http_1.0.47.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:326) [com.ibm.ws.transport.http_1.0.47.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:167) [com.ibm.ws.channelfw_1.0.47.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:75) [com.ibm.ws.channelfw_1.0.47.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.requestComplete(WorkQueueManager.java:504) [com.ibm.ws.channelfw_1.0.47.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.attemptIO(WorkQueueManager.java:574) [com.ibm.ws.channelfw_1.0.47.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.workerRun(WorkQueueManager.java:958) [com.ibm.ws.channelfw_1.0.47.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager$Worker.run(WorkQueueManager.java:1047) [com.ibm.ws.channelfw_1.0.47.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.threading.internal.ExecutorServiceImpl$RunnableWrapper.run(ExecutorServiceImpl.java:239) [com.ibm.ws.threading_1.1.47.jar:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1160) [?:1.8.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) [?:1.8.0]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:822) [?:2.9 (03-19-2021)]
Caused by: com.ibm.jsse2.util.j: PKIX path building failed: com.ibm.security.cert.IBMCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at com.ibm.jsse2.util.h.a(h.java:120) ~[?:8.0 build_20201204--193]
    at com.ibm.jsse2.util.h.b(h.java:5) ~[?:8.0 build_20201204--193]
    at com.ibm.jsse2.util.g.a(g.java:10) ~[?:8.0 build_20201204--193]
    at com.ibm.jsse2.bq.a(bq.java:32) ~[?:8.0 build_20201204--193]
    at com.ibm.jsse2.bq.a(bq.java:26) ~[?:8.0 build_20201204--193]
    at com.ibm.jsse2.bq.checkServerTrusted(bq.java:171) ~[?:8.0 build_20201204--193]
    at com.ibm.jsse2.y$c.a(y$c.java:97) ~[?:8.0 build_20201204--193]
    ... 85 more
Caused by: com.ibm.security.cert.IBMCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at com.ibm.security.cert.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:139) ~[?:8.0 build_20200819-68]
    at com.ibm.security.cert.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:124) ~[?:8.0 build_20200819-68]
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:292) ~[?:?]
    at com.ibm.jsse2.util.h.a(h.java:124) ~[?:8.0 build_20201204--193]
    at com.ibm.jsse2.util.h.b(h.java:5) ~[?:8.0 build_20201204--193]
    at com.ibm.jsse2.util.g.a(g.java:10) ~[?:8.0 build_20201204--193]
    at com.ibm.jsse2.bq.a(bq.java:32) ~[?:8.0 build_20201204--193]
    at com.ibm.jsse2.bq.a(bq.java:26) ~[?:8.0 build_20201204--193]
    at com.ibm.jsse2.bq.checkServerTrusted(bq.java:171) ~[?:8.0 build_20201204--193]
    at com.ibm.jsse2.y$c.a(y$c.java:97) ~[?:8.0 build_20201204--193]
    ... 85 more
```

My local build works fine with no error but after deployment to the test-server the error occours. Firewall is open for the target.

I hope we can add mor debug to find a solution for the issue.

Comment: The address I'm calling is certificated from the company and all certificates and certificationspaths should be in the keystore deployed with the WLP. The local keystore should be the same but I'm using it via the JRE and not in the server.xml

Answer (score 0):

We've got one step further with a workmate. He enabled SSL-debugging in the wlp and we saw that java took the default certfile. The correct one is configured directly in the wlp.
When you take httpClient 4 you build the sslcontext with
`javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.getDefault` und you get the sslContext of the wlp. But this context isn't working in httpClient 5 and I can't find a translation. So for now we have built back to httpClient 4 and SSL is working.